# EXCEL VBA: Compare then Update/change, remove and add between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm comparing 2 worksheets in the same Workbook, row by row (and each cell of the row) this code its able to identify which of the row has been changed(CHANGE),  if doesn't exist in the second sheet then show it as removed (REMOVE), or if this only exist in the second sheet this needs to be added (ADD).
So the tab in the work sheet are:

ORIGINAL \ UPDATED \ CHANGES

What I trying to achieve is to create a fourth one (FINAL) with all the changes applied, but before I could even get there I found some problems with the code (BTW source and template found  at: [here](http://chandoo.org/forum/threads/comparing-two-spreadsheets-for-changes.10054/#post-57562))It works great(with the REMOVE and ADD), but when using a great number of registries (hundreds) some of them, flagged as **changes** doesn't  display the right values, and sometimes, reworking in the same tabs and trying to apply the the Macro again  gets error at the marked line(*).

I.E.: 
ORIGINAL          \          UPDATED          \          CHANGED

**Car_01 |500| ms**      \          **Car_01 |750 |ms**     \        **Car_01| 15.5| ms**

At first I approach the problem thinking it was something related with the type of parameter at the cells vs the input it has to be in the macro but so far I haven't found the right type (already have try it: General, Number and Text). So any scope in the solutions of how to display the fourth sheet and the problem with the values types will be greatly appreciate it.

```
Sub CompareSheets()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' constants
'  worksheets & ranges
'   original
Const ksWSOriginal = "ORIGINAL"
Const ksOriginal = "OriginalTable"
Const ksOriginalKey = "OriginalKey"
'   updated
Const ksWSUpdated = "UPDATED"
Const ksUpdated = "UpdatedTable"
Const ksUpdatedKey = "UpdatedKey"
'   changes
Const ksWSChanges = "CHANGES"
Const ksChanges = "ChangesTable"
'  labels
Const ksChange = "CHANGE"
Const ksRemove = "REMOVE"
Const ksAdd = "ADD"
'
' declarations
Dim rngO As Range, rngOK As Range, rngU As Range, rngUK As Range, rngC As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim I As Long, J As Long, lChanges As Long, lRow As Long, bEqual As Boolean
'
' start
Set rngO = Worksheets(ksWSOriginal).Range(ksOriginal) '(*)here gets marked the error of the debugger
Set rngOK = Worksheets(ksWSOriginal).Range(ksOriginalKey)
Set rngU = Worksheets(ksWSUpdated).Range(ksUpdated)
Set rngUK = Worksheets(ksWSUpdated).Range(ksUpdatedKey)
Set rngC = Worksheets(ksWSChanges).Range(ksChanges)
With rngC
    If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
        Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).ClearContents
        Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
        Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).Font.Bold = False
    End If
End With
'
' process
lChanges = 1
'  1st pass: updates & deletions
With rngOK
    For I = 1 To .Rows.Count
        Set c = rngUK.Find(.Cells(I, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            ' deletion
            lChanges = lChanges + 1
            rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksRemove
            For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngO.Cells(I, J).Value
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
            Next J
        Else
            bEqual = True
            lRow = c.Row - rngUK.Row + 1
            For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                If rngO.Cells(I, J).Value <> rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value Then
                    bEqual = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next J
            If Not bEqual Then
                ' change
                lChanges = lChanges + 1
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksChange
                For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                    If rngO.Cells(I, J).Value = rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value Then
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngO.Cells(I, J).Value
                    Else
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbMagenta
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
                    End If
                Next J
            End If
        End If
    Next I
End With
'  2nd pass: additions
With rngUK
    For I = 1 To .Rows.Count
        Set c = rngOK.Find(.Cells(I, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            ' addition
            lChanges = lChanges + 1
            rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksAdd
            For J = 1 To rngU.Columns.Count
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
            Next J
        End If
    Next I
End With
'
' end
Worksheets(ksWSChanges).Activate
rngC.Cells(2, 3).Select
Set rngC = Nothing
Set rngUK = Nothing
Set rngU = Nothing
Set rngOK = Nothing
Set rngO = Nothing
Beep
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As additional note, I test different methods to apply this solution (LOOKUP, ...) but so far this was my best approach.

---

I have located the error of the CHANGE status, and is related to absolute reference in the loop, for instance: 
ORIGINAL tab has a value in **row 505** parameter **Car_Red** has a value of **23**
UPDATED tab has the same parameter (**Car_Red**) but in the **row 575** with value **27**
The code notice the difference, but instead of copy this new value, it will get the value from the UPDATED tab in the row **505** (as the ORIGINAL tab location of that value), so I guess somehow we need another variable to catch the new value of the parameter to use it as reference for the UPDATED tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the info is not sorted VLOOKUP, INDEX-MATCH doesn't work great with the multiple sheets, to update the right info in this unsorted list it was necessary to create an additional sub:

```
Sub CopyRealChange()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim tempName As String
Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
Dim s2Row As Long, s1Row As Long

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UPDATED")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

lastRow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'Get last row for both sheets
lastRow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    ' searching both

For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2                              'Loop through "CHANGES"
    If sh2.Cells(s2Row, 1).Value = "CHANGE" Then
        tempName = sh2.Cells(s2Row, 2).Value           'extra step for understanding concept
                                                       'There is a match, so now
        For s1Row = 2 To lastRow1                      'Search through the other sheet
            If sh1.Cells(s1Row, 1).Value = tempName Then
                sh2.Cells(s2Row, 3).Value = sh1.Cells(s1Row, 2).Value    'Copy Values
                sh2.Cells(s2Row, 4).Value = sh1.Cells(s1Row, 3).Value
            End If
        Next s1Row
    End If
Next s2Row
```

End Sub

And found out in almost every case of compare it wasn't necessary to create a 4th tab with the change because the updated version already contains all the info and was redundant

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the extract below from the first listing.

```
rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
```

should be

```
rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value
```

As `I` refers to the row position in the `Original` file while `lRow` refers to the matching entry row position in the `Update` file.

```
For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
   If rngO.Cells(I, J).Value = rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value Then
      rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngO.Cells(I, J).Value
   Else
      rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
      rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbMagenta
      rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
   End If
Next J
```